# Making a local image directly appear in a chat and not waiting for network image (Streambuilder / Firebase)

Tags: listview, flutter, stream-builder

Please explain it for a beginner ;-).

**Goal:** When sending an image via WhatsApp, it directly appears in the chat (WhatsApp doesn't "wait" for the upload). I want the same effect.

My issue is, that the image is selected via imagepicker, then there is a delay until it is displayed in the chat, because Streambuilder -> ListView.builder only shows it if its written in the database).

**Currently, I have these steps:**

1. imagepicker
2. image file is compressed and uploaded (async, await…)
3. image is stored in Firebase
4. url of the file is received and written into Firestore database as a field to the message via _handleSubmitted
5. Streambuilder -> Listview.builder shows all messages (images via CachedNetworkImage), received as a snapshot via *(document["imageUrl"])*

**My idea:** First, display the local image from imagepicker within the Listview.builder, which is then replaced by the network image (smooth transition).

But since I started with programming just 3 weeks ago, I have no idea how to do it or even manipulate list items within the Listview.Builder.

```
//Chat screen which lists all the chat messages, including _handleSubmitted and the _buildTextComposer

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_image/flutter_native_image.dart';
import 'package:first_app/image_large.dart';

final database = Firestore.instance
    .collection('nachrichten')
    .document('G5xlQHvb56ZqpWs7ojUV');
final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages');

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new ChatScreenState();
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  bool _isComposing = false;
  bool isLoading;
  String imageUrl;
  File imageFile;

  //optional from other code
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageUrl = '';
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      uploadFile();
    }
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    //file compression
    File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(imageFile.path,
        quality: 50, percentage: 50);
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(compressedFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
      imageUrl = downloadUrl;
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        _handleSubmitted(imageUrl: imageUrl);
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
    });
  }

  //Builds the button text composer, including camera icon, text input and send button
  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return new IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.80),
          child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.4),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                onPressed: getImage,
              ),
            ),
            new Flexible(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),

                //container with constraint limits the maximum height of the text input field
                child: new Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromHeight(100.0)),
                  child: new TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    controller: _textController,
                    onChanged: (String text) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isComposing = text.length > 0;
                      });
                    },
//                    onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: "Nachricht schreiben..."),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.4),
                child: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                    ? new CupertinoButton(
                        child: new Text("Send"),
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(text: _textController.text)
                            : null,
                      )
                    : new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(text: _textController.text)
                            : null,
                      )),
          ]),
          decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
              ? new BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                      new Border(top: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])))
              : null),
    );
  }

  //Builds the actual chat screen with Scaffold
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Chat.here Gruppenchat"),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation:
              Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? 0.0 : 4.0),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('nachrichten')
              .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
              //  .limit(20)
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data');
            final int documentsLength = snapshot.data.documents.length;
            return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Flexible(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      reverse: true,
                      itemCount: documentsLength,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                        final DocumentSnapshot document =
                            snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        return new Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                          child: new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                child: new CircleAvatar(
                                    child: new Text(
                                        document['author'].substring(0, 1))),
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                child: new Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        new Text(document['author'],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                                color: Colors.black45,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        new Text(
                                            ' ' +
                                                DateFormat("MMM. d. '|' HH:mm")
                                                    .format(
                                                        document['timestamp']),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                                color: Colors.black45))
                                      ],
                                    ),

                                    (document['text'] == null)
                                        ? new GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        SecondScreen(
                                                            imageUrl: document[
                                                                'imageUrl'])),
                                              );
                                            },
                                            child: new Container(
                                              child: new ClipRRect(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    new BorderRadius.circular(
                                                        7.0),
                                                child: new CachedNetworkImage(
                                                  imageUrl:
                                                      document['imageUrl'],
                                                  placeholder: Container(
                                                    child:
                                                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                      valueColor:
                                                          AlwaysStoppedAnimation<
                                                                  Color>(
                                                              Colors.orange),
                                                    ),
                                                    width: 200.0,
                                                    height: 200.0,
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(70.0),
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.all(
                                                        Radius.circular(8.0),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              margin:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0),
                                            ))
                                        : new Card(
                                            margin:
                                                EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0),
                                            //green color for messages of yourself
                                            color:
                                                document['author'] == "Matthias"
                                                    ? Color.fromRGBO(
                                                        220, 255, 202, 1.0)
                                                    : null,
                                            child: new Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                                child: new Text(
                                                  document['text'],
                                                  style:
                                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                                )),
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
                                          ),

                                    //Container( child: image != null ? new Image.file(image, width: 250.0) : new Text("Kein Bild"))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )),
                    new Divider(height: 1.0),
                    new Container(
                      decoration:
                          new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
                      child: _buildTextComposer(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                    ? new BoxDecoration(
                        border: new Border(
                            top: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])))
                    : null);
          }),
    );
  }

  void _handleSubmitted({String text, String imageUrl}) {
    _textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _isComposing = false;
    });

    //creation of an own document in Firestore
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
      CollectionReference reference =
          Firestore.instance.collection('nachrichten');

      await reference.add({
        "text": text,
        "author": "Matthias",
        "imageUrl": imageUrl,
        "timestamp": DateTime.now(),
      });
    });

    _scrollController.animateTo(
      0.0,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show it with `Image.file` from the location on the device until the upload is complete.

For example with

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: const FileImage(pathToFile),
  image: NetworkImage(uploadedFileUrl),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 256,
),
```

Comment: I tried this: FadeInImage(
  placeholder: const Image.file(imageFile.path),
  image: NetworkImage(document['imageUrl']),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 256.0,
) …….IDE gives me this errors: The argument 'Image' can't be assigned to the type 'ImageProvider'. The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.

Comment: Try `Image.file` instead of `FileImage`. Have trouble remembering when to use which.

Comment: Already tried it with Image.file - I now tried FileImage - now the errors are gone, but the entire chat (text+images) disappears at start. When I then post an image, it all loads. Still, I have no idea how to implement the placeholder until upload is complete.

Comment: The entire chat (text+images) disappears. sounds like a different problem

Comment: Well the chat is perfectly working if I am using CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: document['imageUrl'], placeholder: Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator()). Only issue: image is posted with delay. How can I "listen" and know, when the upload is complete in my code?

Comment: How do you upload?

Comment: Have a look at the functions getImage(), which is my imagepicker, and uploadFile(), which does the file upload, in my posted code. I then use handleSubmitted() to write the url of the uploaded file to the Firestore database.

Comment: When you get the URL upload is completed. Xou might want to use `precacheImage()` to know when download is completed.

Comment: I honestly have no clue how to do it. So the image gets uploaded via async to Firebase. I only get the firebase url of the image when the images is already uploaded? Then streambuilder returns list.viewbuilder which displays the entire stream of all messages (and images based on this url). So how can I now measure that the upload of the actual image file is not completed and show a local image, and when the upload is completed "silently" replace it with the network image of firebase?

Comment: You should be able to get the URL immediately but you have the code to get the URL after `await uploadTask.onComplete;` and thus will only be executed after upload is complete. Not sure what you need to measure. You probably want to hold the current upload/download state for each image somewhere. Yes, then replace it after download is complete because then it can be shown without delay with `NetworkImage` because it's already in the cache.

Comment: Yes, you re right. on.Complete seems to be the issue. Any idea how to get the URL while it's still uploading, or isnt it necessary? Any concrete suggestion to my code? It's just to advanced for me...if i am leaving out on.Complete, IDE says: StorageUploadTask cant be assigned to a variable of type StorageTaskSnapshot.

Comment: Move the code to get the  URL before the upload code. I haven't tested but I think it should work.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time ;-). `await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl)` is the code to get the URL. If I move it in front of `StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete`, then storageTaskSnapshot isn't defined. But why do I have to get the URL? I only need it if the upload is already complete, i.e. when the file is already uploaded. Honestly, no idea how to progress further ;-).

Comment: I see. Sorry, I don't have the time to fully dive into your problem. You asked how to get the URL before upload. I also don't think you need it.